# How to get data from a form and post it into iframe to emulate a forum?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, iframe, forum

So I have a **form**...

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Post a comment:</legend>
<form target="forum" method="post" action="forum.**SomeKindOfExtension**" >
                Name: <br />
        <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
                Subject:<br />
        <input type="text" name="subject" size="50"/><br />
                Comment:<br />
<textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="100">Hello,</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then I want to take the **data** (name, subject and comment) and put that into an **iframe** on the **click of the button** `<input type="submit" value="Send" />`...

The iframe is on the same page as the form (below it) and looks like this...

```
<iframe name="forum" src="forum.**SomeKindOfExtension**" 
width="900" height="500" ></iframe>
```

Using PHP would mean submitting the form to a server, which would refresh the entire page, not just an iframe which is all that needs to refresh so Javascript would be better I suppose.

Once the text data has been inputted I wanted the iframe to store that data there permanently. Basically like a forum within an iframe.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form to your PHP file (`action="yourfile.php"`), but **target** the Iframe in your form. Process the form on the server and spit out the result. It will appear in the Iframe.

Comment: Thanks! 

What do I need to target the iframe to? The PHP file?

How do I process the form on the server?

Comment: You don't target the iframe to anything. It *IS* the target of the form. As for processing the form, that should be a separate question. The answer is already out there if you look.